# Jenkins deploy into multiple openshift environments and ALM Maintenance

Tags: jenkins, deployment, openshift

I'm a bit newbie on Jenkins so I have this question.
I am currently working on a project about CD. We are using jenkins to build a docker image, push it to the registry and deploy into OpenShift afterwards...Although this process works like a charm there is a tricky problem i'd like to solve. There is not only 1 openshift but 3 (and increasing) environments/regions where I want to deploy this images.

This is how we are currently doing:

Setting region tokens as secret text

$region_1 token1

$region_2 token2

$region_3 token3

Then

> build $docker_image
>
> push $docker_image to registry
>
> deploy into Region1.ip.to.openshift:port  -token $region_1
>
> deploy into Region2.ip.to.openshift:port  -token $region_2
>
> deploy into Region3.ip.to.openshift:port  -token $region_3

Thus, in case we need to new any new "region" to the Jenkins Jobs, we have to edit every job manually...

Since the number of docker images and also the number of Openshift regions/enviromnets is increasing, we are looking for the way to kind of "automate" or make it easier as possible when it comes to add a new Openshift region, since ALL the jobs (old and new ones) must deploy their images into those new environment/regions...

I have been reading documentation for a while but Jenkins is so powerful and have so many features/options that somehow i get lost reading all the docs...

I dont know if doing a Pipeline process or similar would help...

Any help is welcome :)